# VSIX package installation with registering custom library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, class-library, add-on

I made a Visual Studio extension using *Roslyn* to analyze and refactor source code. I work on a custom attribute that is declared in another project in the solution, and in my analyzer, I search for that attribute. My project structure is like below:

- CustomAnalyzer.Base (Class library)

  - CustomAnalyzer.Base.MyCustomAttribute.cs (My attribute class)
- CustomAnalyzer (Analyzing and Refactoring methods)
- CustomAnalyzer.Vsix (VSIX package project)

*CustomAnalyzer* project has a reference to *CustomAnalyzer.Base*. I want that programmers be able to add *CustomAnalyzer.Base.MyCustomAttribute* annotation in top of their methods after installing extension on their **Visual Studio**. But when I install the extension, I cannot add a reference to *CustomAnalyzer.Base* since this library is not in assemblies list.

How can I register my Class Library as an Extension or Framework Assembly when the extension has been installed?

Answer (score 0):

please sign your class library project with package project key.snk.

right click project -> Properties -> signing -> enable sign the assembly -> click the dropdownlist below -> Browser... -> select key.snk file in the project named HelloWorld2Parter -> Open -> rebuild your project.

[image]

Comment: I did it as you described, but still it doesn't register my assembly, so I don't have access to assembly in References management in Visual Studio

Comment: @Amin, Do you want to register your dll file separately like using the Regasm.exe or others?https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f692ca33-1e74-4251-973a-e9883ee6e16b/registering-my-class-dll-with-references?forum=netfxbcl